# SSRS Group Summary - Multiple Records in Single Row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-grouping

I need to reformat an SSRS document to summarize the same Item and Lot Numbers on one line instead of breaking them out on individual lines by the PKG #.

For example:

```
ITEM1234, LOT1234, PKG #'s 1 - 5, 8, 11, 16
```

The current format is as such:

```
ITEM1234 / LOT1234 / PKG1 
ITEM1234 / LOT1234 / PKG2 
ITEM1234 / LOT1234 / PKG3 
ITEM1234 / LOT1234 / PKG4 
ITEM1234 / LOT1234 / PKG5 
ITEM1234 / LOT1234 / PKG8 
ITEM1234 / LOT1234 / PKG11
ITEM1234 / LOT1234 / PKG16
```

Ideally, we would like to see the item and lot on one line, and a combination of all packages on only **one** line following, turning this 8 line combo in 2 lines.

```
ITEM1234 / LOT1234 
PKG 1,2,3,4,5,8,11,16
```

Does anyone have an idea on how would we go about doing this?

Comment: You can do this with two Row Groups and one Column Group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a table to group by both your ITEM and LOT numbers and add a second line for the second line of data.

To concatenate the package numbers, you could use the LOOKUPSET function to get the data and the JOIN function to convert the multiple lines of data to a single string.

```
="PKG " & 
Join(LookupSet(Fields!ITEM.Value & Fields!LOT.Value
    , Fields!ITEM.Value & Fields!LOT.Value
    , REPLACE(Fields!PACKAGE.Value, "PKG", "")
    , "DataSet1"), ", ")
```

The REPLACE function is used to get rid of the PKG in front of each number.

Comment: This seems to be working well. However, the package numbers are coming in out of sort order, even though the dataset is sorted as such. Do you know of anyway to fix this?

Comment: I would think that if the query sorted the data, that the Lookupset would have the same order. There is a custom function that might work for you - **JoinSorted**. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bobmeyers/2012/06/18/create-short-lists-using-the-lookupset-function/

Comment: Definitely a step in the right direction, thanks! Now the only problem is I am dealing with numbers, and they aren't being treated as integers, so the sort still isn't 100% accurate. Any idea how to combat this?

Comment: Try add a CINT around the lookup value to see if converting the data works - `CINT(REPLACE(Fields!PACKAGE.Value, "PKG", "")`. Otherwise I would try padding the value with spaces so it sorts by the spaces first - `RIGHT("      " & REPLACE(Fields!PACKAGE.Value, "PKG", ""), 6)`. In your expression to show the value, you'd also need to replace spaces with nothing - `="PKG " & REPLACE(Join...  ..."DataSet1"), ", ") , " ", "")`